# Excel table.combine({Sheet1},{Sheet2}) erases data on an append

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a power query combination that looks like this:

```
= Table.Combine({#"Sheet1", #"Sheet2"})
```

Now the tables combine, and most of the data appends, but some rows are missing in the combined sheet. My first sheet (Sheet1) looks something like this:

{Sheet1}

| Index | Date | Product ID | Totals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4/15/2021 | ABC | 2 |
| 2 | 4/18/2021 | BCA | 1 |
| 3 | 4/19/2021 | CAB | 3 |
| 4 | 4/21/2021 | ABC | 1 |

Second sheet is this:

{Sheet2}

| Index | Date | Product ID | Totals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4/14/2021 | ABC | 0.0 |
| 2 | 4/16/2021 | BCA | 0.0 |
| 3 | 4/17/2021 | CAB | 0.0 |
| 4 | 4/20/2021 | ABC | 0.0 |

And when I run:

```
= Table.Combine({#"Sheet1", #"Sheet2"})
```

I get something like this:

{Sheet3}

| Index | Date | Product ID | Totals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4/15/2021 | ABC | 2 |
| 2 | 4/18/2021 | BCA | 1 |
| 3 | 4/14/2021 | ABC | 0.0 |
| 4 | 4/16/2021 | BCA | 0.0 |
| 5 | 4/17/2021 | CAB | 0.0 |
| 6 | 4/20/2021 | ABC | 0.0 |

Now I've refreshed this query a million times, and this query has worked for months up until this point. Additionally, the data populating in Sheet1 and Sheet2 are queried from Sharepoint, so the data is successfully able to be pulled into excel without errors, and the append is working with the exception of a few rows, but it's baffling me why it's not appending the way I expect it to, 1 for 1 per the two sheets.